# Insert Multiple Rows to table after select and change Values rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

:)
i have a table the Includ any row.

Names Rows my Table is:

ID_ImgPhoto(PK),IDPhoto(FK),Title,Small,Larg,AddedDate,AddedIp,Status.

i want read at the DataReader in asp.net and change string the String.replace() many Values Small And Larg row in my table.
i want Insert Multiple Rows to table after select and change The Same Values rows.
i want select many row With a Condition.

My select Code Is:

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[sp_Tbl_ImagePhotoGraphy_SelectRow]
    @IDPhoto int
As
Begin
    Select 
        [ID_ImgPhoto],
        [IDPhoto],
        [Title],
        [Small],
        [Larg],
        [AddedDate],
        [AddedIp],
        [Status]
    From Tbl_ImagePhotoGraphy
    Where
        [IDPhoto] = @IDPhoto
End
```

i Want changed value many rows after the give Value @IDPhoto And select Many Row my table and FOR EXAMPLE :

```
    /*OLD DATA*/
ID_ImgPhoto     IDPhoto     Small                   Larg
1               1           OLD/1S.jpg              OLD/1L.jpg
2               1           OLD/2S.jpg              OLD/2L.jpg
3               1           OLD/3S.jpg              OLD/3L.jpg
4               2           Oldsmall/1S.jpg         OldLarg/1L.jpg
5               2           Oldsmall/1S.jpg         OldLarg/1L.jpg
5               2           Oldsmall/1S.jpg         OldLarg/1L.jpg
5               2           Oldsmall/1S.jpg         OldLarg/1L.jpg
____________________________________________________________________
/*NEW DATA Afetr Select And Chnage Rows Value*/
ID_ImgPhoto     IDPhoto     Small                   Larg
1               1           NEW/1S.jpg              NEW/1L.jpg
2               1           NEW/2S.jpg              NEW/2L.jpg
3               1           NEW/3S.jpg              NEW/3L.jpg
4               2           Oldsmall-2/1S.jpg       OldLarg-2/1L.jpg
5               2           Oldsmall-2/1S.jpg       OldLarg-2/1L.jpg
5               2           Oldsmall-2/1S.jpg       OldLarg-2/1L.jpg
5               2           Oldsmall-2/1S.jpg       OldLarg-2/1L.jpg
```

Comment: i find this sulotion.
UPDATE MYTBLE set small=replace(small,'OLD/','NEW/'),larg=replace(larg,'OLD/','NEW/')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I FIND THIS Sulotion.:)

UPDATE yourtable set small=replace(small,'OLD/','NEW/'),larg=replace(larg,'OLD/','NEW/')